# Microsoft Custom Translator: File upload not working for SC tmx files

Tags: microsoft-translator, machine-translation

I am testing the new Microsoft Custom Translator and trying to train a system EN-SC, but the file upload fails.

I am trying to upload unzipped TMX files, all less than 50 MB in size, as specified in the user's guide. The file names I have tried are:

*Master1_en-us_zh-cn.tmx, Master2_en_zh.tmx, Master3_zh-cn.tmx,*

in case the filename format had something to do with this.

I have successfully uploaded files and trained an EN-Spanish system using the same procedure, so I am not sure what I may be doing wrong.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on where to look for errors.

Comment: Odds of getting this answered are low. I'd suggest to add more details of error messages etc.

Comment: Thank you. I don't get any error messages. There is an inmediate message saying "Your document is uploading. Large files may take a while to complete", but then it fails quietly. I have tried IE, Chrome and Firefox browsers and various combinations of language ISO codes in the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We indeed identified an issue related to Chinese tmx files that we are working to resolve now.  The problem is that many of the abbreviations used in the tmx files to identify Chinese simplified are not resolving properly.  The work around for now is exactly what you did: to change the abbreviation used in your tmx file to identify Chinese TUs to zh-hans rather than zh, zh-chs or zh-cn.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - I have managed to submit files for training by editing the TMX to globally search&replace the target language code from zh-CN to zh-Hans. – maria c laguardia 5 hours ago